# How to find the limit of the following series based on a new operation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Lets define an operation as $$a*b=a+b+ab$$  Now I need to find the following limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1}*\frac{1}{4}*\frac{1}{9}*\frac{1}{16}\cdots*\frac{1}{n^2}$$
Now I observed the series and found that it is nothing but the sum of the magnitude of  coefficients of the equation except for the first term $$\prod_{i=1}^{n}(x-\frac{1}{i^2})$$ Now to get the sum of coefficients I substituted the value of $x$ as $-1$ thus the answer will be  $$\prod_{i=1}^{n}(-1-\frac{1}{i^2})-1$$ After this I could not proceed. My first doubt was that for $n$ odd value will be negative , and secondly I am not able to evaluate this limit.$$\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}(1+\frac{1}{i^2})$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If

$$x_n = \frac{1}{1} * \frac{1}{4} * \frac{1}{9} * \cdots * \frac{1}{n^2}$$

then

$$x_n = x_{n-1} * \frac{1}{n^2} = (1 + x_{n-1})\left(1 + \frac{1}{n^2}\right) - 1,$$

so

\begin{align}1 + x_n &= (1 + x_{n-1})\left(1 + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)\\
& = (1 + x_{n-2})\left(1 + \frac{1}{(n-1)^2}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)\\
&\quad\vdots\\
& = \prod_{j = 1}^n \left(1 + \frac{1}{j^2}\right).\\
\end{align}

Now

$$\prod_{j = 1}^n \left(1 + \frac{1}{j^2}\right) \to \frac{\sinh \pi}{\pi}\quad \text{as}\quad n\to \infty$$

using the product formula

> $$\sin \pi z = \pi z \prod_{j = 1}^\infty \left(1 - \frac{z^2}{j^2}\right)$$

and substituting $z = i$.

It follows that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = \frac{\sinh \pi}{\pi} - 1.$$

Comment: Can you give me d proof of the product formula, or some references that have a proof of it

Comment: I suggest you take a look in Marsden's complex analysis, for Weierstrass product factorizations. Now, if you know the infinite product representation of the Gamma function, then this sine product product follows from the Euler reflection formula $\sin(\pi z) = \pi/[\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1 - z)]$.

Answer (score 2):

About the product, note that holds $$\sinh\left(x\right)=x\prod_{k\geq1}\left(1+\frac{x^{2}}{k^{2}\pi^{2}}\right)$$
 so$$\prod_{k\geq1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k^{2}}\right)=\frac{\sinh\left(\pi\right)}{\pi}.$$

Comment: What's d name of the first result that you posted, can you attach a proof, or some references related to the result

Comment: @avz2611 It follows from Weierstrass factorization theorem.